# mutate across all columns and compute the differences between two dates

Tags: r, dplyr

I have some data which looks like:

```
                 jobPosition1               jobPosition10                 jobPosition2               jobPosition11
1   ago. de 2020 ? actualidad dic. de 2002 ? ago. de 2003  ene. de 2011 ? oct. de 2012 ene. de 2016 ? ago. de 2017
2 abr. de 2005 ? ago. de 2006 ene. de 2014 ? ago. de 2018 jul. de 2000 ? sept. de 2002 oct. de 2002 ? abr. de 2005
3                                                                                                                 
4                 2006 ? 2009 abr. de 2016 ? dic. de 2018  abr. de 2016 ? dic. de 2018 ene. de 2002 ? may. de 2013
                  jobPosition3               jobPosition12
1  feb. de 2005 ? oct. de 2006 jun. de 2004 ? ene. de 2005
2 sept. de 2006 ? ene. de 2014  sept. de 2018 ? actualidad
3                                                         
4  ene. de 2008 ? dic. de 2012 ene. de 2019 ? ago. de 2020
```

I would like to split the columns into two temporary columns by the `?` sign and then convert them to a date and finally compute the time difference between the two dates - returning a single column for each of the `jobPositionX`'s.

i.e.
`ago. de 2020 ? actualidad` would return 2 months.
`abr. de 2005 ? ago. de 2006` would return 18 months (or 1.5 years).

What I currently have is:

```
    across(d, str_split_fixed(string = ., pattern = "?", n = Inf)) # 1) which does not work

# However I can use the below to apply to a single column "jobPosition1"

str_split_fixed(string = d$jobPosition1, pattern = "\\?", n = Inf) %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate(
    across(everything(), ~str_remove_all(string = ., pattern = "\\.|de")),
    across(everything(), ~str_trim(.)),
    across(everything(), ~str_replace_all(string = ., pattern = "actualidad", replacement = Sys.Date())) # 2) which does not work
    )
```

1. How can I apply my code across all columns of the data frame
2. How can I replace "actualidad" with Sys.Date such that I can then use the function `month` from the `lubridate` package.

Data:

```
structure(list(jobPosition1 = c("ago. de 2020 ? actualidad", 
"abr. de 2005 ? ago. de 2006", "", "2006 ? 2009"), jobPosition10 = c("dic. de 2002 ? ago. de 2003", 
"ene. de 2014 ? ago. de 2018", "", "abr. de 2016 ? dic. de 2018"
), jobPosition2 = c("ene. de 2011 ? oct. de 2012", "jul. de 2000 ? sept. de 2002", 
"", "abr. de 2016 ? dic. de 2018"), jobPosition11 = c("ene. de 2016 ? ago. de 2017", 
"oct. de 2002 ? abr. de 2005", "", "ene. de 2002 ? may. de 2013"
), jobPosition3 = c("feb. de 2005 ? oct. de 2006", "sept. de 2006 ? ene. de 2014", 
"", "ene. de 2008 ? dic. de 2012"), jobPosition12 = c("jun. de 2004 ? ene. de 2005", 
"sept. de 2018 ? actualidad", "", "ene. de 2019 ? ago. de 2020"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach can be close to what you want. Your dates are in Spanish format and sometimes there are only years and also `sept.` is not properly formated. You can reshape to long the data, separate the rows by `?` and then with the use of ids cleaning your text chains. If you want to compute other kind of difference in the dates you ca further explore `lubridate` package. I have computed the diff in dates by months and then reshape to wide. Here the code where I have used the data you shared as `d` (There is a white row, so I have set a filter in the data pipeline to remove that and avoid issues). Here the code using `tidyverse` functions:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#Code
d2 <- d %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep = '\\?') %>%
  mutate(value=trimws(value)) %>%
  filter(value!='') %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>% mutate(id2=paste0('D',1:n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id2,values_from=value) %>%
  #Format years
  mutate(D1=ifelse(nchar(D1)==4,paste0('ene. de ',D1),D1),
         D2=ifelse(nchar(D2)==4,paste0('ene. de ',D2),D2),
         D1=gsub('actualidad',format(Sys.Date(),'%b. de %Y'),D1),
         D2=gsub('actualidad',format(Sys.Date(),'%b. de %Y'),D2),
         D1=gsub('sept','sep',D1,fixed=T),
         D2=gsub('sept','sep',D2,fixed=T)) %>%
  #Now format dates
  mutate(Date1=as.Date(paste0('01 ',D1),'%d %b. de %Y'),
         Date2=as.Date(paste0('01 ',D2),'%d %b. de %Y')) %>%
  #Compute diff in months
  mutate(Diff=interval(Date1, Date2) %/% months(1)) %>%
  select(c(id,name,Diff)) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = name,values_from=Diff)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 7
# Groups:   id [3]
     id jobPosition1 jobPosition10 jobPosition2 jobPosition11 jobPosition3 jobPosition12
  <int>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>
1     1            1             8           21            19           20             7
2     2           16            55           26            30           88            24
3     4           36            32           32           136           59            19
```

And the partial output with all variables is next and can be useful for any change you may wish to make:

```
#Code 2
d3 <- d %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>% pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  separate_rows(value,sep = '\\?') %>%
  mutate(value=trimws(value)) %>%
  filter(value!='') %>%
  group_by(id,name) %>% mutate(id2=paste0('D',1:n())) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id2,values_from=value) %>%
  #Format years
  mutate(D1=ifelse(nchar(D1)==4,paste0('ene. de ',D1),D1),
         D2=ifelse(nchar(D2)==4,paste0('ene. de ',D2),D2),
         D1=gsub('actualidad',format(Sys.Date(),'%b. de %Y'),D1),
         D2=gsub('actualidad',format(Sys.Date(),'%b. de %Y'),D2),
         D1=gsub('sept','sep',D1,fixed=T),
         D2=gsub('sept','sep',D2,fixed=T)) %>%
  #Now format dates
  mutate(Date1=as.Date(paste0('01 ',D1),'%d %b. de %Y'),
         Date2=as.Date(paste0('01 ',D2),'%d %b. de %Y')) %>%
  #Compute diff in months
  mutate(Diff=interval(Date1, Date2) %/% months(1))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 18 x 7
# Groups:   id, name [18]
      id name          D1           D2           Date1      Date2       Diff
   <int> <chr>         <chr>        <chr>        <date>     <date>     <dbl>
 1     1 jobPosition1  ago. de 2020 sep. de 2020 2020-08-01 2020-09-01     1
 2     1 jobPosition10 dic. de 2002 ago. de 2003 2002-12-01 2003-08-01     8
 3     1 jobPosition2  ene. de 2011 oct. de 2012 2011-01-01 2012-10-01    21
 4     1 jobPosition11 ene. de 2016 ago. de 2017 2016-01-01 2017-08-01    19
 5     1 jobPosition3  feb. de 2005 oct. de 2006 2005-02-01 2006-10-01    20
 6     1 jobPosition12 jun. de 2004 ene. de 2005 2004-06-01 2005-01-01     7
 7     2 jobPosition1  abr. de 2005 ago. de 2006 2005-04-01 2006-08-01    16
 8     2 jobPosition10 ene. de 2014 ago. de 2018 2014-01-01 2018-08-01    55
 9     2 jobPosition2  jul. de 2000 sep. de 2002 2000-07-01 2002-09-01    26
10     2 jobPosition11 oct. de 2002 abr. de 2005 2002-10-01 2005-04-01    30
11     2 jobPosition3  sep. de 2006 ene. de 2014 2006-09-01 2014-01-01    88
12     2 jobPosition12 sep. de 2018 sep. de 2020 2018-09-01 2020-09-01    24
13     4 jobPosition1  ene. de 2006 ene. de 2009 2006-01-01 2009-01-01    36
14     4 jobPosition10 abr. de 2016 dic. de 2018 2016-04-01 2018-12-01    32
15     4 jobPosition2  abr. de 2016 dic. de 2018 2016-04-01 2018-12-01    32
16     4 jobPosition11 ene. de 2002 may. de 2013 2002-01-01 2013-05-01   136
17     4 jobPosition3  ene. de 2008 dic. de 2012 2008-01-01 2012-12-01    59
18     4 jobPosition12 ene. de 2019 ago. de 2020 2019-01-01 2020-08-01    19
```